# F# / Argu - How to display help for two level command tree without throwing exception

Tags: f#, command-line-arguments

I have a two-level F# / Argu command tree. Its abbreviated version looks like that:

```
[<CliPrefix(CliPrefix.Dash)>]
type RunContGenArgs =
    | [<Unique>] [<EqualsAssignment>] [<AltCommandLine("-ql")>] MaxQueueLength of int

with
    interface IArgParserTemplate with
        member this.Usage =
            match this with
            | MaxQueueLength _ -> "max queue length."
and
    [<CliPrefix(CliPrefix.None)>]
    ContGenArguments =
        | [<Unique>] [<AltCommandLine("run")>]      RunContGen of ParseResults<RunContGenArgs>
    with
        interface IArgParserTemplate with
            member this.Usage =
                match this with
                | RunContGen _ -> "run Continuous Generation."
```

which, I then use as follows:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<ContGenArguments>(programName = "ContGen.exe")
    let results = parser.Parse argv

    match results.GetAllResults() |> ContGenTask.tryCreate with
    | Some task -> task.run()
    | None ->
        printfn "%s" (parser.PrintUsage())
        -1
```

If I run the command like `ContGen.exe run help`, then it correctly displays help for the command `run`. However, it then crashes with ugly exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Argu.ArguParseException: USAGE: ContGen.exe runcontgen [help] [-maxqueuelength=<int>]
OPTIONS:
    -maxqueuelength, -ql=<int>
                          max queue length.
    help                  display this list of options.
   at Argu.ExceptionExiter.Argu-IExiter-Exit[a](String msg, ErrorCode errorCode) in C:\Users\eirik.tsarpalis\devel\public\Argu\src\Argu\Types.fs:line 62
   at Argu.ArgumentParser\`1.Parse(FSharpOption\`1 inputs, FSharpOption\`1 configurationReader, FSharpOption\`1 ignoreMissing, FSharpOption\`1 ignoreUnrecognized, FSharpOption\`1 raiseOnUsage) in C:\Users\eirik.tsarpalis\devel\public\Argu\src\Argu\ArgumentParser.fs:line 180
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\GitHub\ClmFSharp\Clm\ContGen\Program.fs:line 8
```

If I change `let results = parser.Parse argv` into `let results = parser.Parse(argv, raiseOnUsage = false)`, then it does not crash but does not display any help message. And then since command `run` can run without any second level argument, the program just keeps going instead of displaying help and quitting.

However, I need `ContGen.exe run help` just display help message and then quit. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you point out which lines in the posted code correspond to the lines mentioned in the error message? Maybe also add them to the post plus a few context lines before each of the mentioned ones.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel The line `let results = parser.Parse argv` will crash with the exception above when I run `ContGen.exe run help`. The lines mentioned in the exception are not mine as they come from Argu :( I have not control over that apart from catching the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a somewhat peculiar behavior of Argu; you need to provide your own exiter to avoid the exception being thrown there.

Something along these lines:

```ml
type NonThrowingExiter() =
    interface IExiter with
        member __.Name = "Exiter" // I don't know what this is used for; I have never seen it appear anywhere
        member __.Exit (msg, code) =
            if code = ErrorCode.HelpText then
                printfn "%s" msg
                exit 0
            else
                printfn "%s" msg // Maybe have code to color the console output red here
                exit 1

To use this, create your `ArgumentParser` like this:

let argumentParser =
    Argu.ArgumentParser.Create<ContGenArguments>(helpTextMessage = "Help requested",
                                                 errorHandler = NonThrowingExiter())
```

(You don't actually need to create a class for this, of course; an object expression will do it just as well.)

Comment: Thanks! An F# "way" seems to return an option type instead of throwing exception.